# Kotlin random number generator

Tags: android, random

This is a question about the inner workings of Realm and the Kotlin Random number generator. When I incorrectly had several Realm transaction instances open on a background thread (as many as 100 by accident), I observed that setting a Realm object field value to kotlin.Random.nextInt() was causing collisions over 20% of the time, which should not happen.

What about Realm (or memory in general) could cause a side effect like this on kotlin.Random?
Intuitively, a random number generator should not be affected by the usage of our local database. Would this also affect behavior like UUID.randomUUID()?

Also, I'm aware the Realm should be closed - I'm genuinely curious why this is happening.

```
open class MyObject: RealmObject {
   var randomField: Int
}

fun test() = scope.launch { // background thread
            var messageDupes = 0
            var r = Realm.getInstance()
            while (idx < 100) {
                r = Realm.getInstance()  // opening of Realm without closing

                val random = Random.nextInt() // Why would this be affected? Has many collisions


                val existing = r.where<MyObject>.equalTo("randomField", random)
                if (existing != null) {
                    collisions++
                }
                
                val obj = MyObject()

                obj.randomField = random //set field to the random value
                r.executeTransaction {
                    it.insert(message)
                }
                idx++
                delay(300L)
            }
            val count = r.where<MyObject>().count()
            log.debug("total objects: $count; collisions=$collisions")
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you open too many **Realm** transaction instances without closing them, it causes memory leak and other computing performance issues.

In your code you are opening a new **Realm** instance in every iteration of the `while` loop without closing them, this can cause a significant memory leak which can cause many unexpected behaviour.

Here is how I would do it:

```
var r = Realm.getInstance()
while (idx < 100) {
    r.executeTransaction { realm ->
        val random = Random.nextInt()
        val existing = realm.where<MyObject>().equalTo("randomField", random).findFirst()
        if (existing != null) {
            collisions++
        }
        val obj = realm.createObject<MyObject>()
        obj.randomField = random
    }
    r.close()
    r = Realm.getInstance()
    idx++
    delay(300L)
}
r.close()
```